# PIP file marked as malware

Tags: python, antivirus

I've tried upgrading python pandas on my windows 10 machine. And I have Bitdefender antivirus running there.

When running `pip install --upgrade pandas` my anti-virus gave me these complaints and blocked the installations:

```
The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdxum80e\numpy_3125462826bd4a658e0fec72a379f0e8\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe

The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lcg06sg9\numpy_a2518ba8a6dd4298873df66f46353683\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe

The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-uyfa77aa\numpy_c516f6abb01f4966ae7966b22e09e5ec\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe.

The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lh6ajcuv\numpy_345c4e048b1b49e28b3ee31531bc724d\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe.

The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l8fvwr0a\numpy_f369f7a40f8d452caf2bed94b42535a8\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe.

The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rdxum80e\numpy_3125462826bd4a658e0fec72a379f0e8\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe.

The file C:\Users\bluet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lcg06sg9\numpy_a2518ba8a6dd4298873df66f46353683\_configtest.exe is infected with Gen:Variant.Bulz.777540. The threat has been successfully blocked, your device is safe.
```

These files were blocked. Is my anti-virus being too paranoid? Or is it right that these files are infected?

Comment: It's almost certainly a false positive.  Bitdefender is prone to that.  You should be able to pull it out of quarantine.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Probably submit the problematic files to the vendor and/or VirusTotal